# Map corners like asterisk symbol in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layouts, mapping

I am trying to make a map like this image in QGIS.

I want to add min/max longitude and latitude and star symbol at the corners.

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Add min/max longitude and latitude

Find the map extent in the map item properties.

[image]

Add text labels at each corner and manually type the longitude and latitude for that corner. Set the rotation of the latitude label to 270 degrees.

If you need to convert from decimal degrees to degrees-minutes-seconds, use the `to_dms` function like this:

for min/max longitude: `[% to_dms( -81.805,'x',3,'suffix')%]`
for min/max latitude: `[% to_dms(41.507,'y',3,'suffix')%]`

If you have lots of maps, try using a map item "grid." It will automatically label points around the outside of the map with their correct lat and long, but it's difficult to get the points exactly at the map corners.

> star symbol at the corners

Add another label at one corner. Type an asterisk symbol (*) or this symbol (✳) into the text item. Make the font size large (eg 36 point font).

Move the label onto the corner of the map. Copy and paste the label and place one at each corner.

[image]

Comment: ✳ is a closer dingbat than *

Comment: @alphabetasoup Good suggestion. I added it to my answer.